# Direction of momentum in a collision

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, momentum, vectors, collision

In a simple perfectly elastic collision 1-D collision, with a ball of mass M_1 striking a rigid wall of mass M_2 head on,also$$M_2>>M_1,$$

[image]

then by law of conservation of momentum. $$\Delta\vec{P}=0$$
$$\vec{p}_{initial}=\vec{p}_{final}$$
Does this also mean that the initial direction of momentum is also same after the collision?
In case of 2d collision. The direction is preserved.

[image]

But in 1st case,
$$M_1\vec{u_1}=-M_1\vec{v_1}$$
This result shows that the direction of momentum after collision reverses but the direction of vector on RHS and LHS of equation should be equal, since $$\Delta\vec{P}=0$$
Why this result is not consistent with momentum conservation?

Comment: Could you be more specific?  What do you expect to happen that is different from what actually happens?

Comment: What is your first case as opposed to? i.e. what is your second case? The big mass m2 will move, carrying away the momentum, or else there would be failure of conservation of momentum

Comment: M2>>M1 results in v2<<v1 and not in the second object being stationary.

Comment: @DavidWhite , i wanted to know whether direction the direction of momentum vector after collision is same as that of the initial vectors in an 1-D collision between a particle and massive wall.

Comment: @naturallyInconsistent . I thought that 2nd object in first case was stationary after collision collision due to more inertia. But it is clear now :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well done, you have spotted something not often noticed by students when learning about the conservation of momentum. Namely, in such a perfect elastic collision between a ball and a wall, the ball, beginning with momentum $\vec{p}$ *must* transfer a momentum of $2\vec{p}$ to the wall! Indeed that is in order for the total momentum to remain the same $$\Delta{P} = \underbrace{\vec{p}}_{\textrm{initial momentum}} - \underbrace{(-\vec{p} + 2\vec{p})}_{\textrm{final momentum}} = 0$$

Because the wall is assumed to be significantly more massive, it of course absorbs this momentum without gaining any speed of its own.